# matomo api timeout on fetching

Tags: javascript, html, matomo

I'm trying to integrate data collected with Matomo within my website but whenever the API is being fetched console says: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I've checked the firewall as well as testing another network. I even set the timout to like 10 mins but it keeps erroring.

Thats what my code currently looks like, maybe there's a mistake

```
var apiUrl = 'https://dummy.matomo.de/';
        var auth_token = 'dummyAuthToken12345';
        // Matomo Site ID
        var siteId = '5';
        // Matomo Method
        var exitPage = '&method=Actions.getExitPageUrls';
 fetch(apiUrl + '?module=API' + exitPage + '&idSite=' + siteId + '&segment=' + companyName + '&token_auth=' + auth_token + '&format=json', {timeout: 60000})
            .then(response => {
var totalVisits = data[0]['nb_visits'];
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am having the same problem.